# How to pass parameter to netsh command

Tags: powershell, networking, powershell-3.0

Please let me know how to pass ipaddress,subnetmask,gateway while execution of the script

Below is the script:

```
$VMNetworkSettings = 'netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0" static x.x.x.x(ipaddress) x.x.x.x(subnet mask) x.x.x.x(gateway)'
```

i have tried the below way to achieve but got an error message as invalid parameter

```
$Ip = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the ip address"
$sub = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the subnet"
$gateway = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the gateway"
$VMNetworkSettings = 'netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0" static $Ip $sub $gateway'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the double quotes (`` `" ``) so that you can use them at the start of the string.

```
$VMNetworkSettings="netsh interface ip set address `"Ethernet0`" static $Ip $sub $gateway"
```